# Convertir una imagen a escala de grises, pero conservando los canales (python)

Tags: python, opencv

Necesito convertir una imagen de color RGB a escala de grises, pero conservando los tres canales. Actualmente estoy utilizando la funcion de openCV:

```
cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Pero claro, esa me la devuelve en un número de canales inferior. ¿Hay alguna forma de pasar la imagen a escala de grises pero que siga teniendo los 3 canales?

Comment: Alguna razón por la que no podrías simplemente regresar la imagen en escala de gris a RGB?

Comment: Necesito tenerla en escala de grises pero con 3 canales

Comment: por eso te digo, lo pasas a escala de grises y luego a RGB... (3 canales) Será la misma información que la imagen en escala de grises, pero con canales RGB

Comment: Asi perderia el blanco y negro no? es que quiero que se quede en blanco y negro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tengo la imagen de una flor:

```
import cv2
imagen = cv2.imread('flor.jpg')
```

[image: Flor con licencia CC]

La conviertes a gris, la cual efectivamente elimina los campos RGB y la cambia a escala de grises.

```
img_gris = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Gris', img_gris)
```

[image: Flor en escala de grises]

Lo que debes hacer para pasarla a tres canales es convertirla nuevamente a RGB:

```
img_convertida = cv2.cvtColor(img_gris, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.imshow('Gris convertida', img_convertida)
```

[image: Flor en escala de grises convertida a RGB]

### ¿Por qué la imagen sigue siendo en escala de grises?

Una vez conviertes la imagen de RGB a escala de grises, no hay vuelta atrás. Sí, pasa a ser de un solo canal (indicando el valor de blanco por cada píxel), y para convertirlo, lo único que se hace es pasar ese canal (digamos que en un pixel su valor en escala de gris es 50) a los 3 canales de RGB (sería rgb(50,50,50)), lo cual te da el mismo color gris, solo que representado como la suma de rojo, verde y azul, en lugar de un porcentaje de blanco.

Para comprobarlo, podemos ver los canales de la imagen RGB convertida:

```
b = img_convertida.copy()
b[:, :, 1] = 0
b[:, :, 2] = 0
cv2.imshow('B-RGB', b)
```

[image: Flor en escala de grises convertida a RGB - Canal azul]

```
g = img_convertida.copy()
g[:, :, 0] = 0
g[:, :, 2] = 0
cv2.imshow('G-RGB', g)
```

[image: Flor en escala de grises convertida a RGB - Canal verde]

```
r = img_convertida.copy()
r[:, :, 0] = 0
r[:, :, 1] = 0
cv2.imshow('R-RGB', r)
```

[image: Flor en escala de grises convertida a RGB - Canal rojo]

Así podemos verificar que es una imagen en escala de grises representada con canales RGB.